# Converting String to DWORD (Assembly x86)

Tags: string, assembly, x86

I am trying to learn how to convert a string to an integer. I think I am pretty close. My code works for numbers under 260. Once the numbers entered are greater than or equal to 260, then it just converts them to 0. I think it might have something to do with the size of a BYTE, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any suggestions?
Some Irvine functions are included, but I'm trying to write my own ReadInt function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the problem. Rather than giving away the answer completely, here's a hint:

The `lodsb` instruction loads one byte into `al` (which is the low 8 bits of `eax`). The rest of `eax` is unchanged. What might cause `eax` to contain extra bits that aren't changed by `lodsb`?

Comment: I guess I am kind of confused because I am quite new to Assembly. I have tried changing lodsb to lodsd, but when I do that, x will always equal 0. It does the same thing if I work with the al registers instead of the eax registers.